# Python-can for loop be written in more efficient way to avoid crash

Tags: python, for-loop

The below code is crashing giving error as all memory is exhausted on Google colab pro+. Can someone please suggest better alternatives instead of for loops?

```
imagePaths1 = list(paths.list_images(data_dir1))
data1 = []
labels1 = []
for imagePath in imagePaths1:
    label1 = 1
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    data1.append(image)
    labels1.append(label1)

data1 = np.array(data1) / 255
labels1 = np.array(labels1)

imagePaths2 = list(paths.list_images(data_dir2))
data2 = []
labels2 = []
for imagePath in imagePaths2:
    label2 = 2
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
    data2.append(image)
    labels2.append(label2)
data2 = np.array(data2) / 255
labels2 = np.array(labels2)

data = np.concatenate((data1, data2), axis=0)
label = np.concatenate((labels1, labels2), axis=0)
```

Comment: How many images?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with the loops, instead of all of the images you are collecting?

Comment: Your `for` loops aren't consuming memory.  The data you're collecting within the loops is what's consuming the memory.  If you want to reduce the amount of memory you use, then process each image within the loop, then discard it before reading the next image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend updating the question with details of your use case. It's hard to know without knowing what you need these datasets for, but here are two suggestions based on my assumptions of your problem:

**If you are only using one image at a time:** Try using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to return the images one by one. This way, you are not loading them all into memory at once.

**Bigger subsets for training:** Since you have data in the form of images with accompanying labels, I suspect you're perhaps doing something related to ML. Again, this depends on your use case, what libraries you're using etc., but if you're using TensorFlow, take a look at [input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_sets_of_files), it solves the problem you have for cases using TF. If you're using some other library, something similar is likely available.